# Arguments are passed incorrectly using argparse

Tags: python, azure, argparse, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I do not understand why arguments are passed incorrectly:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--start_date', type=str, default='2016-07-01T00:00:00Z', dest='start_date')
parser.add_argument('--end_date', type=str, default='2016-09-01T00:00:00Z', dest='end_date')
args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()

print(str(args.start_date))
# 01/01/2019 00:00:00 

print(str(args.end_date))
# 08/20/2019 00:00:00
```

This is how I pass arguments to the script from Azure ML pipeline script:

```
    start_date = '2019-01-01T00:00:00Z'
    end_date = '2019-08-20T00:00:00Z'

    preprocess_step = PythonScriptStep(
        name="Test",
        script_name="myscript.py",
        compute_target=aml_compute,
        source_directory=".",
        arguments=[
            "--start_date", start_date,
            "--end_date", end_date
        ],
        allow_reuse=False,
    )
```

If, however, I run `myscript.py` from command line, the parameters are passed correctly:

```
python myscript.py --start_date 2019-01-01T00:00:00Z --end_date 2019-08-20T00:00:00Z
```

What is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: it looks like a formatting issue, right? same date, but formatted differently? Interesting because you define them as strings, but it looks like in one of the processes, somewhere that date is being converted to a datetime object (and so then printed with a different format) before it gets printed

Comment: not very helpful to the problem, but you aware that both `type` and `dest` are unnecessary? `str` is the default for arguments and the name of the argument (without the `--`) is the default for `dest`

Comment: When I execute your minimum working example I do not see the same behavior - I get the values printed out exactly as they are defined in the `default`. Are you 100% sure that there isn't something else converting these to `datetime` objects that isn't shown in any of the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your real environment is only from your post description, but just according to the offical document for classes [`PythonScriptStep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.python_script_step.pythonscriptstep?view=azure-ml-py) and [`RunConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.runconfiguration?view=azure-ml-py), as the figures below, I think there is missing a `RunConfiguration` object assigned for parameter `runconfig` of your `PythonScriptStep` object.

Fig 1. The description of `arguments` and `runconfig` of `PythonScriptStep` class marked in red

[image]

Fig 2. The description about using `RunConfiguration` when setting up a `PythonScriptStep` marked in red

[image]

As references, you can refer to these offical samples list below.

1. [MLOps/examples/customer_churn/Customer Churn.ipynb](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOps/blob/b06e61d00219d7850524b794b958ba3b5a336959/examples/customer_churn/Customer%20Churn.ipynb)
2. [MLOps/examples/AzureML-Primers/06 - Automating ML Workflows with Pipelines.ipynb](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOps/blob/3d34518e3efe462b8e815b40752012271f2ba5fd/examples/AzureML-Primers/06%20-%20Automating%20ML%20Workflows%20with%20Pipelines.ipynb)
3. [MLOps/examples/imagenet-transfer-learning/mlpipeline.py](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOps/blob/682d1e37f5ecafa4db0a813c027232c79e3cd0cc/examples/imagenet-transfer-learning/mlpipeline.py)
4. [MLOpsPython/ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r.py](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/65c07936f763bfb1e6fab9805c51af36447c5e22/ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline_with_r.py)
5. [MLOpsPython/ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline.py](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython/blob/65c07936f763bfb1e6fab9805c51af36447c5e22/ml_service/pipelines/diabetes_regression_build_train_pipeline.py)

They above all assign a `runconfig` value for `PythonScriptStep`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed I use `runconfig`. Sorry that I haven't mentioned it in the post. '`run_config = RunConfiguration(conda_dependencies=CondaDependencies.create(
        pip_packages=['azure', 'azureml-core']))`. But still I misunderstand how `runconfig` is related to the fact that the date strings are converted to date objects.